# Alternate of installing Microsoft Office Access Database Engine 2007

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence, msbi, script-task

I am having a SSIS script task from which I have written some logic to write SQL query results to excel file.

I am using the connecting string as `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, but again it is asking to install Microsoft Office Access Database Engine 2007 which is not allowed to download and install in my server due to some licence issue.

If any alternate connection provider will be suggested then its really appreciated and helpful.

Comment: May I have anybody's suggestion/advise over here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution to this. We can use EP PLUS or any 3rd party DLL's and make the excel connectivity happen through C#/VB.Net script. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can you share a bit more information please?